# Akka and Throttling

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, throttling

I am new to Akka and want to use it for throttling messages.
I want to use the Akka java libraries
I was looking at the following example for version 2.4.2 but unfortunately it is now outdated and not supported
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/contrib/throttle.html

For the latest version (2.5.3) - I found the following in the migration guide for throttling
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#timerbasedthrottler

Would anyone be able to provide a guide example on how to handle throttling in Akka 2.5.3 using the Java framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The second link you provided already has an example. The java example is right below the scala one.

Also, there's another example here, with a bit more description:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html#time-based-processing

Comment: Perfect thanks for this. I got the example working. I am trying now to throttle a service method call from my RestController class. Do you know if this is supported / recommended?

Comment: Spring RestController? I don't have experience using that with akka. akka-http is a very natural fit here.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a lot of services to update and we wont be allowed to switch to akk-http